# Stopping my embedded Youtube Videos on click

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, pause

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I've tried a number of solutions but I'm totally stuck on this:
I have a number of embedded videos from YouTube on my Site and I have navigation buttons. I want the videos to be paused as soon as any of the buttons are clicked, no matter how many of them are playing at that time. I embedded them the classic way by using the iframe code that YouTube gives you when clicking "embed" and gave them the ".yt" class.

My function currently looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    
    $('#shadingleft').on('click', function () {
        rotateLeft();
        reset();
        selector = selector - 1;
        if (selector <= -1) {
            selector = 9;
        }
        $('.clicked').toggleClass('clicked');
    })
    
    $('#shadingright').on('click', function () {
        rotateRight();
        reset();
        selector = selector + 1;
        if (selector >= 10) {
            selector = 0;
        }
        $('.clicked').toggleClass('clicked');
    })
    
    $('#shadingtop').on('click', function () {
        rotateUp();
        $('.clicked').toggleClass('clicked');
    })
    
    $('#shadingbottom').on('click', function () {
        rotateDown();
        $('.clicked').toggleClass('clicked');
    })
    
    $('.art').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    })
    
});
```

As you can see I already managed to toggle the highlighted ".art" elements in my gallery using toggleClass. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for playing and pausing videos.
Whenever one of the four "shading..." elements is clicked I want my ".yt" elements to stop playing the embedded video.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Here is an example on how to embed a video and use functions with it (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls). Apparently there is a `player.stopVideo();` when you create the iframe in the code. With embedded videos you should take a look at https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#enablejsapi . From there you can try further.

Comment: The problem with the functions they show there is that they refer to a "player"-ID. I have multiple videos though so I would need a solution that addresses an entire class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a actually a big limitation with iframes. Most browsers won't allow a page's scripts to interact with the content of its iframes for security reasons. So chances are that there is no way at all to do that.

One way you could stop videos would be to reload the youtube iframe entierly, but that would put it back to 00:00 as if it was never played.

Another would be to try and fetch the video stream from youtube on your server and then displaying it in a player of your own on your page. (Which is obviously way more complicated than using an iframe)